# How do you determine if a docker container is running on remote docker-machine or locally running in docker engine?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

To push the concerns of internet bandwidth to a cloud computer, I run my docker container on a remote docker-machine. This kind of set-up is very handy when you have pretty slow internet. My problem is that I don't know how to easily determine the host of a container.

This is how I determine it:

Run this, `docker run -d -p 8000:80 nginx` and visit --> `localhost:8000`; if it returns a nginx default page, then I know it's running the docker container locally.

If I replace `localhost` with docker-machine ip and get the nginx page, then I know the container is on a remote system.

Comment: Do you want to know which host your `docker run` commands will target? Then probably `docker-machine ls` will show you the currently active machine.

Comment: A little confused over your question. What are you looking for? From what I can see there is you are doing a `-p` which port maps the container's port 80 to the host's 8000. So I suppose your either you do localhost:8000 or machine-ip:8000 it will still work for both cases

Comment: @AndreasJägle Yes I want to know what host docker run targets. I've tried, docker-machine ls, and there were times when remote host  machine was running, but the docker container was resided on the localhost.

Comment: @SamuelToh thanks for taken interest. My question is, how do you ensure that when you create a docker container that it get created on a remote docker machine.

Comment: Please provide an example (commands and output) where `docker-machine ls` shows you will start a container remotely but it actually runs locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker` CLI is the client half of a client/server architecture (`dockerd` or in past versions `docker daemon` is the other half). When you use `docker-machine`, it is updating environment variables including `$DOCKER_HOST` which tells `docker` to connect to another host. The default is to connect to the socket on the local host. The value of `$DOCKER_HOST` overrides that, and the CLI flag `docker -H ...` overrides both of those.

The most common reason to have a container spin up on an unexpected host is when you forget to set/unset `$DOCKER_HOST`.